# .Net Window service equivalent in linux?

Tags: linux, service

Can we hook to similar start,stop etc events. Do we have to write them as shell scripts? I know of mono port of .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something called an 'init script'. These are scripts that allow you to start or stop a service with a single command, like so:

```
service httpd restart
service httpd stop
service httpd start
```

Some Linux distributions do not include the `service` command, in which case you access init scripts directly by their location, `/etc/init.d`, like so.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

You can program your init script to accept whatever parameters you want (start, stop, restart, etc). Some basic tutorials on writing init scripts to get you started can be found at the following web pages:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-write-init-script-376302/

Many times an init script is unnecessary, and you can just go with the simpler option of executing your program in the background and killing it manually. Running an executable on Linux in the background can be done like so:

```
./some_prog arg1 arg2 &
```

And killing it is done like this:

```
kill `pgrep some_prog`
```

If you are fairly new to Linux, that latter option might be a much easier way to go until you get a handle on init scripts and the general Linux service ecosystem.

Comment: thanks for the excellent answer Maxwell.As in ur example, I am more interested in knowing how would you code`httpd`.I guess `httpd` is witten C/C++.

Comment: I would basically write a background service for a website(say for sending weekly newsletters or processing recurring payments in background etc). Do I need to code this service `httpd` way?

Comment: Ah, yes, my answer was about how you would control httpd, not actually write it. If you want to do some task at a preordained time and repeat it at some specified interval, the tool you are looking for is cron. It is actually very convenient and easy to use once you get the hang of it. A brief overview can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron.

You edit your crontab with `crontab -e`. Just write a script to do whatever you want, tell cron how often to do it, and cron will automatically do it for you as often as you specify, in the background.